# Cleaner code to save array data with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I created a function to save data into mongoDB with logic below, but I really have difficulty to refactor the code and make it cleaner, there are so many annoying code duplication, how can I have DRY principle?

Logic:
1. pass in a flag to decide either close DB connection or not at end.
2. create different mongoDB models according to the passed in `returnedArray` and save into DB.

```
var saveArrayToDB = function(returnedArray, flagToCloseDBConnection) {
    var objectToSave,
        object,
        type = returnedArray[0].type,
        arrayToSave = [];

    if (type === 'user') {
        for (var i = 0; i < returnedArray.length; i++) {
            object = returnedArray[i];
            objectToSave = new User({
                fullName: object['full_name'],
                activatedAt: object['activated_at'],
                location: object['location'],
                timezone: object['timezone'],
                imageURL: object['mugshot_url'],
                stats: object['stats']
            });
            arrayToSave.push(objectToSave);
        }

        User.create(arrayToSave, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err ' + err);
            }
            if(flagToCloseDBConnection) {
                mongoose.connection.close();
            }
        });
    } else if (type === 'group') {
        for (var j = 0; j < returnedArray.length; j++) {
            object = returnedArray[j];
            objectToSave = new Group({
                fullName: object['full_name'],
                createdAt: object['created_at'],
                stats: object['stats'],
                url: object['web_url']
            });
            arrayToSave.push(objectToSave);
        }

        Group.create(arrayToSave, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('err ' + err);
            }
            if(flagToCloseDBConnection) {
                mongoose.connection.close();
            }
        });
    } else {
        objectToSave = null;
        console.log('ERROR: unrecognized type in data. Not saved.');
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to add on to what [@JohnnyHK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259510/johnnyhk) commented on your question, it would be best if you keep your mongoose connection open during your application lifecycle. Other than that you could use some JavaScript functions like **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** to initialize the arrays, define common callback functions that you can reuse in both create and map methods:

```
var saveArrayToDB = function(returnedArray, flagToCloseDBConnection) {
    var type = returnedArray[0].type,
        arrayToSave = [];

    var callback = function(err) {
        if (err) {  console.log('err ' + err); }
    };

    var newUser = function(u){
        return new User({
            fullName: u['full_name'],
            activatedAt: u['activated_at'],
            location: u['location'],
            timezone: u['timezone'],
            imageURL: u['mugshot_url'],
            stats: u['stats']
        });
    };

    var newGroup = function(g){
        return new Group({
            fullName: g['full_name'],
            createdAt: g['created_at'],
            stats: g['stats'],
            url: g['web_url']
        });
    };


    if (type === 'user') {      
        arrayToSave = returnedArray.map(newUser);       
        User.create(arrayToSave, callback);
    } else if (type === 'group') {
        arrayToSave = returnedArray.map(newGroup);
        Group.create(arrayToSave, callback);
    } else {
        console.log('ERROR: unrecognized type in data. Not saved.');
    }

};
```

Comment: Elegant code! I know `map()` but didn't know well enough to use it flexibly like you did here.
This code is not part of web servers, it is meant to run in back-end by admin to refresh data regularly. Once the data is refreshed, the DB connection should be closed.

I would mark this as the solution

Comment: @XiXiao Thanks. At least it's readable and with your use-case then you should be able to add the connection close logic appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

No need for closing the connection. Here's an already much improved version:

```
var factories = {
    'user': {
        method: function(object){
            return {
                fullName: object['full_name'],
                activatedAt: object['activated_at'],
                location: object['location'],
                timezone: object['timezone'],
                imageURL: object['mugshot_url'],
                stats: object['stats']
            };
        },
        model: User
    },
    'group': {
        method: function(object){
            return {
                fullName: object['full_name'],
                createdAt: object['created_at'],
                stats: object['stats'],
                url: object['web_url']
            };
        },
        model: Group
    }
}

var saveArrayToDB = function(returnedArray) {
    var saveQueue=[],
        factory = factories[returnedArray[0].type];
    if(!factory){
        return console.log('ERROR: unrecognized type in data. Not saved.');
    }

    returnedArray.forEach(function(item){
        saveQueue.push(factory.method(item));
    });

    factory.model.create(saveQueue, function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log('err ' + err);
        }
    });
};
```

(You don't need to pass document instances, plain objects are good enough for Model.create)

Comment: Have you tested this? Just by inspection, this line `saveQueue.push(factory.method(item));` will throw an error because `factory` is not an object, rather a string (from `factory = returnedArray[0].type;`). I believe you need to create the factory object first or just do `saveQueue.push(factories[factory].method(item));`

Comment: thanks for sharing your thought! using a `factories` definitely helps here. I wonder if it makes code more readable to pass instance instead of plain object?